# Google script app delay without freezing spreadsheet calculation

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

How can I have delay on Google Script App function without freezing the spreadsheet calculation.

sleep function freezing all spreadsheet calculation, and I have many calculation on the spreadsheet that I want to finish before the next step.

How can I solve that?

Comment: flush() doesn't help too

Answer (score 1):

Use `SpreadsheetApp.flush();` to apply the changes made by the script before the sleep statement.